# How to display data in ionic 3?

Tags: android, laravel, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I cannot display data in ionic. How can I display the data in ionViewWillEnter and using post method in laravel API?

I have tried to call the data using console.log to check if the data is there or not. I tried "console.log(this.id);" before this.authService in ionViewWillEnter as shown below.

**kprofile.ts**

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.authService.postData(this.id,'viewProfileClinic').then((result) => {
          this.responsedata = result;
          console.log(result);
              this.usersClinic.email = this.responsedata.email;
                this.usersClinic.telno = this.responsedata.telno;
                this.clinic_regno = this.responsedata.clinic_regno;
                this.clinic_name = this.responsedata.clinic_name;
                this.site = this.responsedata.site;
                this.clinic_address = this.responsedata.clinic_address;
                this.zip = this.responsedata.zip;
                this.city = this.responsedata.city;
                this.state = this.responsedata.state;
        },(err) =>{

        });
  }
```

as I console.log result is shown

> no clinic data

as I run ionic serve.

below is the api
**.api**

```
    //VIEW ALL CLINIC PROFILE
        public function viewProfileClinic(Request $request)
        {
            $id =$request->id;
            $clinicID = $request->clinic_id;

            $count = RegisterClinic::where('clinic_id',$clinicID)->count();
            if($count == 1)
            {
                $clinicData = RegisterClinic::where('clinic_id',$clinicID)->first();        
                $callEmailTelno = User::where('id',$clinicData->uid)->first();

                $datamsg = response()->json([
                        'calldata' => 'Email:'.$callEmailTelno->email.' Telno:'.$callEmailTelno->telno
                                     .' Clinicregno:'.$clinicData->clinic_regno.' Clinicname:'.$clinicData->clinic_name
                                     .' Site:'.$clinicData->site.' Clinicaddress:'.$clinicData->clinic_address
                                     .' Zip:'.$clinicData->zip.' City:'.$clinicData->city.' State:'.$clinicData->state

                    ]);
                    return $datamsg->content();
            }
            else{

                $datamsg = response()->json([
                    'error' => array("text"=>"No clinic data.")
                ]);
                return $datamsg->content();
            }
        }
```

This is what I want it to be displayed in ionic in .html file.

**.html**

```
<ion-list>
<p>Clinic Profile</p>
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" class="list-form">
        <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Clinic Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="usersClinic.email" [(ngModel)]="usersClinic.email">{{usersClinic.email}}</ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Telephone no.</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="usersClinic.telno" [(ngModel)]="usersClinic.telno">{{usersClinic.telno}}</ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <button ion-button color="light" class="transparent-button" [disabled]="!f.valid" text-center round>
          Edit
        </button>
      </form>
      <ion-item>
        <p>Clinic Registration no</p>
        {{clinic_regno}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <p>Clinic Name</p>
          {{clinic_name}}
      </ion-item> 
      <ion-item>
          <p>Clinic Site</p>
          {{site}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <!-- <p>Clinic Address</p>  -->
          <ion-label primary>Clinic Address</ion-label>
           <!-- <ion-textarea>{{clinic_address}},{{zip}},{{city}},{{state}}.</ion-textarea> -->
           <ion-textarea rows="6" disabled [value]="clinic_address" ></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>


    </ion-list>
```

the api response in postman is as below.

> {"calldata":"Email:jumin@hu.cm Telno:0148232323 Clinicregno:87234824 Clinicname:Klinik Ikhlas  Site:www.wuu Clinicaddress:UTC Central Market Zip:87000 City:Labuan State:Wilayah Persesekutuan Labuan"}

Below is my 
**authService.ts**
file which I put my postData method.

```
postData(credentials, type) {

    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('API Response : ', response.json());
          resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
          console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
          reject(error.json());
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: so `console.log` shows that `no clinic data`. Some issue with the way in which you are calling the api.

Comment: Use ngOnInit(){ }  instead

Comment: Please check your api. You are getting response via Postman and no response through your app. Please check this first.

Comment: where should I  use the ngOnInit(){}?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you, but for my API response it came in as json also but instead of me extracting it as json I ran:

> this.responsedata = (JSON.stringify(result));

Then,

> this.responsedata = JSON.parse(this.responsedata);

Also, another possibility may be the API not formatting the data correctly. I'm sure you've echoed your data on the API, but there may be an issue with something there because you're getting the else callback. So maybe start with the if statement.

P.S.- Sometimes the headers can be a pain if not formatted correctly, if you're passing a token or any type of data in your headers sometimes Angular/Ionic is a little more sensitive than postman to the data.

Comment: where did you put the >this.responsedata = (JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: Inside your promise from the results parameter in the kprofile.ts

Comment: ok, I actually have this authservice.ts file for my API response. I have updated the question at the end part.